# Dompdf with table pdf contains error

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm using dompdf 0.6.0 beta 3 in a cakephp 1.3 application as vendor. The php version of my server is 5.2. The pdf I generate as attachment containes tables generated with html helper and the css is declared in the header.

I have a very strange problem. Usually there is no problem with the generated pdf but in about 10 percent of the generated pdf, the file contains an error and is only partially rendered. There is no fatal error but somehow the pdf generation is not right. Even stranger, it occurs with exactly the same datas that the php code takes in Session variables. So the same datas are sometimes generated without any problem (in 90% of the cases) and sometimes there is a problem.

Thank you if you have a clue about what the problem could be.

Here is the code that generates the pdf. (Journal is a helper I created and the function Journal::journalCheck outputs a table)

```
$html = 
'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'.
    '<head>'.
        $this->Html->charset().
        '<style>

            ul{
                margin: 0px;
            }
            .enonces p{
                margin:0px;
            }
            table{
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width:100%;
                margin-bottom: 25px;
            }    
            table.legende{
                width:25%;
            }

            td{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            th{
                border: 1px solid black;
                background-color: #96ed88;
            }
            .noEcriture{
                width:5%;
            }

            .nomCompte{
                width:15%;
            }

            .montantCompte{
                width: 10%;
                text-align: right;
            }

            .libelle{
                width: 45%;
                min-width: 65px;
            }
            .faux{
                color: red;
                text-decoration:line-through;
            }
            .ecriture_fausse{
                background-color: pink;
            }
            td.correction_cell{
                background-color: #daafe7;
            }
            .consigne{
                font-style:italic;
            }

            .enonces{
                border: 1px solid black;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

        </style>'.
    '</head>'.
    '<body>'.
        '<h1>'.
            $exercice[0]['Exercice']['nom'].
        '</h1>'.
        '<h3>'.
            'Exercice réalisé par '.$session->read('eleve.Exercice.prenom').'                            '.$session->read('eleve.Exercice.nom_famille').
            ' - version '.$session->read('exercice.'.$this->params['pass'][0].'version').
            ' - '.date('d/m/Y').
        '</h3>'.
        '<p class="consigne">'.
            $this->Journal->showConsigne($exercice[0]['Exercice']['consigne'],$raw = true).
        '</p>'.
        '<div class="enonces">'.
            $this->Journal->viewEnonce($enonces).
        '</div>'.
        $this->Journal->journalCheck($datas,$correct_datas,$ecriture_ids,$compte_ids,array('pdf'=>true)).
        '<p>'.
            'Légende:'.
        '</p>'. 
        '<table class="legende">'.
            $this->Html->tableCells(array(array('écriture juste'),
                                    array(array('écriture fausse',array('class'=>'ecriture_fausse'))),
                                    array(array('corrigé',array('class'=>'correction_cell'))))
                                    ).
        '</table>'.       
        '<p>'.
            'Source: <a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".basename(ROOT)."/"."exercices/complete/".$this->params['pass'][0].'">'.
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".basename(ROOT)."/"."exercices/complete/".$this->params['pass'][0].'</a>'.             
        '</p>'.
    '</body>'.
'</html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("Journalizer_".$exercice[0]['Exercice']['nom']."_".$session->read('eleve.Exercice.nom_famille')."_".$session->read('eleve.Exercice.prenom')."_v".$session->read('exercice.'.$this->params['pass'][0].'version').".pdf", array("Attachment" => 1));
```

Comment: "Somehow the PDF generation" is not enough info for anyone to help you :) Try to put together some examples.

Comment: Sorry, here you'll find two screen shots of a corrupted pdf file. First, there should not be any blank page in the first part of the file: [see here] (http://www.lacompta.ch/MITIC/Images/Capture3.PNG). Then, the table is not rendered until the end (line 18 misses one cell). And there should be another table below this one: [see here] (http://www.lacompta.ch/MITIC/Images/Capture4.PNG)

Comment: So the document is exactly the same each time? It might help to see a sample of the HTML that's giving you problems. Also, even though there is no fatal error, there could be some kind of other problem affecting the output.

Comment: I edited my question with the code that generates the pdf. What's really strange for me is that with exactly the same datas, it most offently outputs well but in 10% of the cases there are errors in the pdf outuput. And even if there is an error and I generate the pdf again, the file renders perfectly well the second time. I really don't understand...

Comment: To help debug the problem you might also try saving both the dompdf HTML and PDF to disk. You can get the HTML and PDF using `$dompdf->output_html()` and `$dompdf->output()`. Run the command until you get a bad render, then compare the good and bad HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time ago. The thing was that dompdf was throwing error when pdf was too big. I cannot find fix for this now because I don't have acces to code any more.

Try to check apache error log file. And if you find this error, then you can google search for answer using error message.

Some simple source one line edit was needed to fix this.